Java Regex replaceAll with double quoted string
I'm trying to replace a part of min("ş".SALARY)
My pattern is:
String fullName = "\"ş\".SALARY";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(fullName) + "\\b",Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);

Matcher:
String expressionTxt="min(\"ş\".SALARY)";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expressionTxt);

and replace:
String newColumnName="EM_PLOYEES_1.SALARY"
matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(newColumnName));

But it is not working, what am I doing wrong?

The problem is with the word boundary: the double quote at the start of the fullName requires the preceding char to be a word char, and in your string, it is a (. So, use "adaptive" (as I call them) word boundaries, "(?!\\B\\w)" + Pattern.quote(fullName) + "(?!\\B\\w)"

…or just drop the first boundary. Unless you can come up with an example of a text that contains "ş".SALARY but should not match due to what precedes that part, there is no need for a boundary at the beginning. That’s an entirely different situation than at the end where the last word character should not be followed by another word character.
